# Magento 2 layered navigation custom collection

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation

I want to implement layered navigation on my custom controller action where I have listed all the products of a particular brand. I have called the layered navigation block on this page but the layered navigation filters are not populated by the product collection attributes.
Please tell me how can I achieve this in magento 2?